# Printing a PDF file and terminating Adobe Reader

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to export a sheet `Sheet1` as a PDF file and print it then close adobe reader using a code.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" 
    (ByVal hwnd As  Long, 
    ByVal lpOperation As String, 
    ByVal lpFile As String, 
    ByVal lpParameters As String, 
    ByVal lpDirectory As String, 
    ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Public Function PrintThisDoc(Formname As Long, FileName As String)
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim X As Long
  X = ShellExecute(Formname, "Print", FileName, 0&, 0&, 1)
End Function

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:="D:\Print.pdf"
  PrintThis = PrintThisDoc(0, "D:\Print.pdf")
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10))
  TerminateProcess
End Sub
```

I use the `.wait` method to pause the code for 10 seconds until the print order is sent to the printer before terminating adobe reader.
But when I add this line, the `TerminateProcess` sub is affected and I get a `Not found error` concerning this line (`intError = objProcess.Terminate`)

```
Sub TerminateProcess()
  Dim strTerminateThis As String
  Dim objWMIcimv2 As Object
  Dim objProcess As Object
  Dim objList As Object
  Dim intError As Integer

  'Process to terminate
  strTerminateThis = "AcroRd32.exe"

  'Connect to CIMV2 Namespace
  Set objWMIcimv2 = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

  'Find the process to terminate
  Set objList = objWMIcimv2.ExecQuery("select * from win32_process where name='" & strTerminateThis & "'")

  'Terminates a process and all of its threads.
  For Each objProcess In objList
      intError = objProcess.Terminate
  Next

  Set objWMIcimv2 = Nothing
  Set objList = Nothing
  Set objProcess = Nothing
End Sub
```

when I remove the `.wait` line, Adobe reader is terminated but nothing is printed as my file is opened and closed in no time.

So any help with that please ??

Comment: The only suggestion I have is to not open it in Adobe Reader in the first place. If you'll note, you can print a PDF from the context menu without actually opening Reader - I recommend looking into how this works...

Comment: This also happens even if I first open the file using shellexecute. Could u explain please what do u mean by printing a PDF from the context menu without actually opening reader ??

Comment: In Windows with Reader installed, right clicking on a PDF in explorer will show "Print" among the options. Choosing this option will print the PDF without opening Reader. You should be able to hook into a similar mechanism to avoid opening Reader in the first place.  Please keep in mind that this is just an idea and may or may not work in your situation.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. But I think trying to achieve this using a code will be so difficult for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a bit simplistic, but why can't you just print the Excel file and not the PDF? They should be the same shouldn't they?